# R: compare multiple columns pairs and place value on new corresponding variable

Tags: r

Am a basic R user.

I have 50 column pairs (example pair is: "*pair_q1*" and "*pair_01_v_rde*") per "*id*" in the same dataframe that I would like to collect data from and place it in a new corresponding variable e.g. "*newvar_q1*".

All the pair variable names have a pattern in their names that can be distilled to this ("pair_qX" and "*pair_X_v_rde*", where X = 1:50, and the final variables I would like to have are "*newvar_qX*", where X = 1:50)

Ideally only one member of the pair should contain data, but this is not the case.

Each of the variables can contain values from 1:5 or NA(missing).

**Rules for collecting data from each pair based on "*id*"  and what to place in their newly created corresponding variable are:**

If one of the pairs has a value and the other is missing then place the value in their corresponding new variable. e.g. ("*pair_q1*" = 1 and "*pair_01_v_rde*" = NA then "*newvar_q1*" = 1)

If both pairs have the same value or both are missing then place that value/missing in their corresponding new variable e.g. ("*pair_q50*" = 1/NA and "*pair_50_v_rde*" = 1/NA then "*newvar_q50*" = 1/NA)

If both pairs have different values then ignore both values and assign their corresponding new variable 999 e.g. ("*pair_q02*" = 3 and "*pair_02_v_rde*" = 2 then "*newvar_q02*" = 999)

Can anyone show me how I can execute this in R please?

Thanks!
Nelly

```
# Create Toy dataset
id <- c(100, 101, 102)
pair_q1 <- c(1, NA, 1)
pair_01_v_rde <- c(NA, 2, 1)
pair_q2 <- c(1, 1, NA)
pair_02_v_rde <- c(2, NA, NA)
pair_q50 <- c(NA, 2, 4)
pair_50_v_rde <- c(4, 3, 1)

mydata <- data.frame(id, pair_q1, pair_01_v_rde, pair_q2, pair_02_v_rde, pair_q50, pair_50_v_rde)


# The dataset
> mydata
id pair_q1 pair_01_v_rde pair_q2 pair_02_v_rde pair_q50 pair_50_v_rde
1 100       1            NA       1             2       NA             4
2 101      NA             2       1            NA        2             3
3 102       1             1      NA            NA        4             1


# Here I manually build what I would like to have in the dataset 
newvar_q1 <- c(1, 2, 1)
newvar_q2 <- c(999, 1, NA)
newvar_q50 <- c(4, 999, 999)


mydata2 <- data.frame(id, pair_q1, pair_01_v_rde, pair_q2, pair_02_v_rde, pair_q50, pair_50_v_rde, newvar_q1, newvar_q2, newvar_q50)

> mydata2

id pair_q1 pair_01_v_rde pair_q2 pair_02_v_rde pair_q50 pair_50_v_rde newvar_q1 newvar_q2 newvar_q50
1 100       1            NA       1             2       NA             4         1       999          4
2 101      NA             2       1            NA        2             3         2         1        999
3 102       1             1      NA            NA        4             1         1        NA        999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using the 'tidyverse' (use 'inner_join(mydata,.,by="id")' to get the new columns in the order you give in your question):

```
mydata %>% 
  select(id,matches("^pair_q")) %>%                  # keeps only left part of pairs
  gather(k,v1,-id) %>%                               # transforms into tuples (id,variable name,variable value)
  mutate(n=as.integer(str_extract(k,"\\d+"))) -> df1 # converts variable name into variable number
mydata %>% 
  select(id,matches("^pair_\\d")) %>%                # same on right part of pairs 
  gather(k,v2,-id) %>% 
  mutate(n=as.integer(str_extract(k,"\\d+"))) -> df2

inner_join(df1,df2,by=c("id","n")) %>% 
  mutate(w=case_when(is.na(v1) ~ v2,      # builds new variable value
                     is.na(v2) ~ v1,      # from your rules
                     v1==v2 ~ v1,
                     TRUE ~999),
        k=paste0("newvar_q",n)) %>%        # builds new variable name from variable number
  select(id,k,w) %>%                       # keeps only useful columns
  spread(k,w) %>%                          # switches back from tuple view to wide view 
  inner_join(mydata,by="id")               # and merges the new variables to the original data

#   id newvar_q1 newvar_q2 newvar_q50 pair_q1 pair_01_v_rde pair_q2 pair_02_v_rde pair_q50 pair_50_v_rde
#1 100         1       999          4       1            NA       1                 #2       NA             4
#2 101         2         1        999      NA             2       1            NA        2             3
#3 102         1        NA        999       1             1      NA            NA        4             1
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas2. Its works as expected. For my and future R newbies can you kindly comment on what each line of code is doing?

Comment: @Nelly I edited my answer hopefully with useful comments.

Comment: Thanks! @Nicolas2